# Cannot get php_curl.dll working with PHP & Apache

Tags: php, windows, apache, curl

I am running PHP 5.6.25 and Apache 2.4.23, both x64, on **Windows 10**. All of the other extensions that shipped with PHP are working except for `php_curl.dll`. Apache keeps giving me the `'C:/PHP/ext\\php_curl.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application` error.

I have:

- Ensured `extension_dir = "C:/PHP/ext"` is correct
- Ensured the file actually exists
- Ensured that PHP and the dll are the same version – they both came from the same binary from windows.php.net
- Added `C:\PHP` and `C:\PHP\ext` to the PATH
- Ensured `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` are in `C:\Windows\System32` and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`

What else can I do!?

Comment: Did you install Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: @simon, Yes, of course!

Comment: x64 builds of PHP 5.6 for Windows are apparently considered experimental. Maybe it helps if you update to PHP 7 or use x86 builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to 32 bit versions of Apache, PHP and OpenSSL got the extension working correctly.

Comment: Note, that "downgrading" the whole surrounding for one extension is not the recommended solution. Before doing that you should download the curl x64 extension manually and check, if it works. After that trying the same with the x86 version. (It´s actually weird, that x64 php complains it shall be x86 version anyway.) For every version PHP 7.0+ this would work, I am not sure for PHP 5 though.